# Python regex verbose with lookahead pattern

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to use the following regular expression to extract the file name `foo.py` and `bar.txt` from the text below with `re.VERBOSE` flag, but it doesn't work, nothing matches. The regex is working fine if I put all the sections into a single line (without the verbose flag).

```
REGEX = r"""
    (?<=: )
    (\S+)
    (?= was lost| is no longer in the repository)                                              
"""
```

Text:

```
cvs.orig update: warning: foo.py was lost
cvs.orig update: bar.txt is no longer in the repository
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of the `re.VERBOSE`, you have to code **all** spaces with `\s`:

```
(?<=:\s)
(\S+)
(?=\swas\slost|\sis\sno\slonger\sin\sthe\srepository)
```

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/mlCm34/1)

Comment: Isn't whitespace is allowed within tokens like `*?`, `(?:` or `(?P<...>`? according to [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.VERBOSE)

Comment: @chunwai: Yes, it is but you don't have such token here.

Comment: I did some tests on these tokens, `(?:`, `(?<=`, `(?=`, all of them are able to match the string in verbose mode if the token contains **only** whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

A bit messy and maybe not the way you're after but it returns the result:

```
# Initialise libraries in session: 
import re

 # Data: lst => list
lst = ["cvs.orig update: warning: foo.py was lost",
"cvs.orig update: bar.txt is no longer in the repository"]

# Each word as its own separate list element: lst_words => list
lst_words = sum([*map(lambda x: re.split('\s+', x), lst)], [])

# Find anything elements ending with .py or .txt, store as list, remove empty 
# elements: list => stdout (console)
sum([*map(lambda x: re.findall('.*\.py$|.*\.txt', x), lst_words)], [])
```